# How to track different authenticated users' actions using Mixpanel

Tags: reactjs, analytics, auth0, mixpanel

I have built a React application. The application requires users to login/signup first using Auth0. I have also implemented Mixpanel into my application to track the events (e.g. `mixpanel.track('Click event A')`). However, I would like to track the actions/events for each different individual user.

For example:
'mary@gmail.com' has clicked on event A for 3 times;
'eric@gmail.com' has clicked on event A for 2 times..etc

Can anyone give me specific steps or directions for how to approach to this purpose ?

P.S: I have read https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004497803-Identity-Management-Best-Practices, it states to use `mixpanel.alias(id)` when users signup and `mixpanel.identify(id)` when users login. However, since I am using Auth0, I am not sure where should I include the `mixpanel.alias(id)`.

Comment: Are you tracking events that happen prior to the user logging in? Or are all of the events you are tracking only accessible after the user has authenticated with Auth0?

Comment: Yes, all the events I am tracking would only be accessible after the user has authenticated with Auth0 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you only track events after the user has logged in (as per your comment) I don't see any reason for you to use `mixpanel.alias`.

When Auth0 successfully authorizes a user call `mixpanel.identify`. Following this the logged in user will be associated with all events that you track.

```
webAuth.popup.authorize({
  redirectUri: 'https://YOUR_APP/popup_response_handler.html'
  //Any additional options can go here
}, function(err, authResult) {
  if(!err){
    mixpanel.identify('USER_ID_HERE');
    mixpanel.track('Successful Login');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixpanel uses a distinct_id to relate each track event with a certain profile on their system.

You can use people set events to enrich the profile with user data.

Alias is the mechanism they have to bind a profile’s history of events to a new id, normally used to correlate the actions of an anonymous user with a random distinct_id to the same user, now registered and with a determined user id.

The major limitation on mixpanel’s implementation is that they can only do 1 alias per profile. So, if a user already did the whole navigate anonymous and signup process, but comes again to your site anonymously and does a login, the second time he navigates anonymously will create a different history track of events that you can’t assign to the user.

Since you only want to track identified users, there’s no need to use alias. 
Mixpanel provides a JavaScript library that automatically creates a distinct_id for any user, identified or not, that navigates to your site and doesn’t have a distinct_id yet. You need to use the library method identify with your user’s id so that instead of sending the track events with the distinct_id, it does so with your user id.

Now, the mixpanel library is quite heavy and does a lot of things you may not need. Like the distinct_id/identify thing I mentioned, plus browser info, domain and other filds that will automatically populate your track events. If you like that, fine.
If not, you can use the http api they have, which is very easy to use. You can simply do a post request indicating the user id and the event tracked, and you will have the same result without having to depend on the library.